# How to claim NFT to my address if my address is approved on the NFT?

Tags: nft

I have my address approved on an nft using setApprovedForAll method, and I want to claim this nft and transfer it to my account. how should I do so?

Answer (score 1):

To perform this action directly on Etherscan, you need to follow the steps below:

Locate The Contract: First, you need to navigate to the contract's page on Etherscan. You can do this by entering the contract address in the search bar on the Etherscan homepage.

Connect Your Wallet: On the contract's page, navigate to the "Contract" tab and click on the "Write Contract" button.

Interact With The Contract: Once your wallet is connected, you can interact with the contract. To transfer an NFT, you'll typically use the transferFrom function. This function usually takes three parameters:

From: The current owner's address
To: Your address
tokenId: The ID of the token you want to transfer
Enter these details in the respective fields and click "Write".

Confirm The Transaction: A MetaMask (or your wallet's) confirmation popup should appear, asking you to confirm the transaction. Make sure the details are correct, and then confirm the transaction.

Wait For Confirmation: The transaction will now be processed. You can click on the transaction hash to monitor the status of the transaction. Once it's confirmed, the NFT should be transferred to your account.

Please note that this is a general guideline and the actual steps might vary slightly depending on the specific contract. If you provide the contract address, I can give more precise instructions.

Also, interacting with contracts directly can be risky if you're not sure what you're doing. Be careful to only interact with contracts you trust, and always double-check the details before confirming a transaction.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.
You might need specific ansfer from creators of this NFT.

Comment: should i use a private key in any of the parameters?

Comment: also how to get the token id?